# Why does this Symbol list cap at 1 page?

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

I have been trying to use the glossaries and the glossaries-extra to generate a list of Acronyms and a List of Symbols.
Acronyms are coming great, and Symbols does so...but just one page; for whatever reason, it ignores new additions to the list:

[image: SymbolList]

I have added in the document many more symbols with \gls{nameOfTheSymbol}, but still it does not add any more symbols to the list. It will create a link that will send me to the first page, but nothing else.
Explaining a bit about what I have done.

First, I call the usepackage:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,xindy,toc]{glossaries}
```

Then before the document:

```
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbols List} % create add. symbolslist
\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}

\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
        \begin{longtable}{lp{0.6\glsdescwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
        {\end{longtable}}%
    %
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
        \bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit \\
        \hline
        \endhead}
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
        & \glsunit{##1}  \tabularnewline
    }
}

 \include{Symbols}
 \include{Acronyms}
```

In Symbols, there are several entries like this:

```
\newglossaryentry{acceleration}{name=a,% the label
    description={Linear Acceleration},% a brief description
    unit={\ensuremath{\frac{m}{s^2}}},
    type=symbolslist% the associate symbol
}
\newglossaryentry{B}{name=B,% the label
    description={Magnetic Flux Density},% a brief description
    unit={\ensuremath{\si{T}}},
    type=symbolslist% the associate symbol
}
```

And already in the document where I would like the glossaries to appear:

```
\glsaddallunused
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]  % list of acronyms
\printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=symbunitlong]   % list of symbols

  \thispagestyle{empty}                 % tables/figures are printed.
  \cleardoublepage                  % Necessary for correct page numbering.
```

Does anyone know what should I do to print the whole list?
Thanks!

Comment: you should edit the question to provide an example, but have you re-run makeglossaries after adding new entries?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the answer! I have re-run makeglossaries after the new entries, but just in case I have done it now again. Same result, but a good point.

Comment: unless you provide an example that shows the problem I doubt this can be answered.

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle, sorry for the late response, busy week. I was prepreparing the example when I spotted the issue. As you said, it was related to makeglossaries. I was executing makeglossaries but with the change in the computer and reinstalling everything the path to Perl was not properly set up. Once all the paths were correct, everything went smoothly. The Acronyms were looking fine as they had not changed much, so it was looking like only Symbols was not getting update. Thanks again!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was a local setup issue solved by OP

Comment: OK thanks for confirming, I voted to close (or you could delete)